# Text::CSV bind_columns not working

Tags: perl, csv, text

When I use this code it won't show any output. It only prints the table tags. Is there something I'm missing?

This is my csv file:

```
id;name;city;
1;name;london;
5;testname;newyork;
7;users;amsterdam;
8;test1234;eindhoven;
```

This is my perl script:

```
#!C:\perl64\bin\perl.exe -wT
use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI;
use CGI::Carp qw/fatalsToBrowser/;
use CGI qw(:standard);
use Text::CSV_XS;

print "Content-Type: text/html\n\n";
my $file = 'import.csv';
my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new({
    'quote_char'  => '',
    'escape_char' => '',
    'sep_char'    => ";",
    'binary'      => 1,
    'eol'         => $/
});

$csv->bind_columns (
                \my $id,
                \my $name,
                \my $city);

open my $fh, "<", $file or die "$file: $!";
print "<table border='1'>";
while($csv->getline($fh)){
    print "
        <tr>
            <td>$id</td>
            <td>$name</td>
            <td>$city</td>
        </tr>";
}
print "</table>";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In [the documentation](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aCSV#bind_columns) for `bind_columns` you can read the following:

> Takes a list of references to scalars to store the fields fetched getline () in. **When you don't pass enough references to store the fetched fields in, getline () will fail.**

And you actually have 4 fields in your lines, but you pass 3 references in `bind_columns`.

```
id;name;city;  # fields "id", "name", "city" and ""
```

The last field is empty. If you add a field to `bind_columns` your code works as expected.

```
$csv->bind_columns (
            \my $id,
            \my $name,
            \my $city,
            \my $blank
);
```

Comment: I read the documentation over and over, but I didn't know I was passing an empty field. Thank you for explanation.

Comment: @9edge You're welcome. You can do a lot more with the CGI module than you are doing, for example print tables and tr/td, the html header, etc. You can pass an array ref to td and get one `<td> .. </td>` for each element, which seems perfect for this case: `while (my $row = $csv->getline($fh)) { print Tr( td($row) ) }` (meaning you can skip `bind_columns`)